# Avoid copying in returning current object

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code implements a methods that either returns a copy of its corresponding object or creates a new object and returns it based on the value of `cond`. Ideally, I wish to change it in a way that if `cond` is true, the method returns it's object not a copy of it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Base {
protected:
std::vector<int> p_;
public:
    Base(std::vector<int>& p) : p_(p.begin(), p.end()) {}
    Base getObj() const {
        if (cond) {
            return *this; // Even if cond is true, I'm copying here. This is what I wish to change.
        } else {
            std::vector<int> p1 = {...};
            return Base(p1);
        }
    }
};



int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {2, 4, 5};
    std::vector<Base> objects;
    Base b(v);
    objects.emplace_back(b.getObj());
}
```

**More Details**

I'm flexible to change the return type of `getObj` to reference or pointer. Nonetheless, I cannot change this vector that holds the output: `std::vector<Base> objects;`

Comment: You want to avoid copying a returned object, but you showed no concern about passing copies, like here: `Base(std::vector<int> p)` -- The vector should be passed by const reference.

Comment: Thank you @PaulMcKenzie for your comment. It's just a toy example that I wrote to ask my question and forgot `&`. Thank you for pointing it out tho. Just fixed it.

Comment: As it is you can't do this. The return value of `getObj()` is a concrete value which will reside on stack, this puts a restriction of where `this` would reside in the first place. How could a `Base` allocated on heap be returned by value without involving a copy? Things could change if you are allowed to move into the returned value so that you can do a cheap move instead that copying instance variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `getObj()`, creating a new object is unexpected from its name. Divide the functions like `isXXX`, `createObj` and `getObj`.